# How to Convert .live() to .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get rid of `"TypeError: $(...).live is not a function"` error. The code is below, I have tried but could not managed to fix it.

```
    $(".search-text input[data-default], .gdlr-comments-area input[data-default]").each(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr("data-default");
    $(this).val(t), $(this).live("blur", function() {
        "" == $(this).val() && $(this).val(t)
    }).live("focus", function() {
        $(this).val() == t && $(this).val("")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the new and old ways to do the same thing as equivalent statements:

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

and more examples:

```
$( "a.offsite" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
$( document ).delegate( "a.offsite", "click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.4.3+
});
$( document ).on( "click", "a.offsite", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" );  // jQuery 1.7+
});
```